# Change background-color if class contains a value

Tags: javascript, background-color

I'm wondering if I can change the background color of a class when it has a specific value.

Example: if the element contains '1' change bg-color to red, if it contains '2' change bg-color to green, etc.

HTML:

```
<div class="skill-points"> 1 </div> <!-- BG color = red -->
<div class="skill-points"> 2 </div> <!-- BG color = green -->
<div class="skill-points"> 3 </div> <!-- BG color = yellow -->
```

CSS:

```
.skill-points {
width: 50px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 4px;
border: 1px solid #000;
text-align: center;
}
```

How should I write my JavaScript code to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all your relevant `class` elements in a collection (using [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) and then convert it to an `array` (using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator). You can then assign background colours using `style.backgroundColor` property.

I have used a mapping object, that can be useful otherwise you can do individual `if` checks too. [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is the property you can use to compare the inner Text of the HTML elements.

```js
let mapping = {
'1' : 'red', '2' : 'green' , '3': 'blue' };

[...document.getElementsByClassName('skill-points')].forEach( x => {
x.style.backgroundColor = mapping[x.innerText];
});
```

```css
.skill-points {
width: 50px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 4px;
border: 1px solid #000;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-points"> 1 </div> <!-- BG color = red -->
<div class="skill-points"> 2 </div> <!-- BG color = green -->
<div class="skill-points"> 3 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your elements, check the `innerText`, and set the element style.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.skill-points').forEach(div => {
  if (div.innerText.contains('1')) div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  ...
});
```

Comment: `HTMLCollection` does not have a `forEach` method.

Comment: @Unmitigated right, thanks - updated

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can get text using `textContent` and match it and set the color as

```js
const allSkillPoints = document.querySelectorAll(".skill-points");

allSkillPoints.forEach(el => {
  const text = +el.textContent.trim();
  if (text === 1) el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  else if (text === 2) el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  else if (text === 3) el.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
})
```

```css
.skill-points {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-points"> 1 </div>
<!-- BG color = red -->
<div class="skill-points"> 2 </div>
<!-- BG color = green -->
<div class="skill-points"> 3 </div>
<!-- BG color = yellow -->
```

**2)** You can also make use of `Map` here as:

```js
const allSkillPoints = document.querySelectorAll(".skill-points");

const map = new Map()
map.set(1, "red")
  .set(2, "green")
  .set(3, "yellow");

allSkillPoints.forEach(el => {
  const text = +el.textContent.trim();
  el.style.backgroundColor = map.has(text) ? map.get(text) : "white";
})
```

```css
.skill-points {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-points"> 1 </div>
<!-- BG color = red -->
<div class="skill-points"> 2 </div>
<!-- BG color = green -->
<div class="skill-points"> 3 </div>
<!-- BG color = yellow -->
```

Comment: You do not need to convert a `NodeList` to an array to call `forEach`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

... what pretty much everyone else said.  Here's my approach:

```js
const valueClassMap = {
  1: "bg-red",
  2: "bg-green",
  3: "bg-yellow"
};
  
document.querySelectorAll(".skill-points").forEach(el => {
  const content = el.textContent.trim();
  if(valueClassMap.hasOwnProperty(content)){
    el.classList.add(valueClassMap[content]);
  } 
});
```

```css
.bg-red{ background: red }
.bg-green{ background: green }
.bg-yellow{ background:yellow }
```

```html
<div class="skill-points"> 1 </div> <!-- BG color = red -->
<div class="skill-points"> 2 </div> <!-- BG color = green -->
<div class="skill-points"> 3 </div> <!-- BG color = yellow -->
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check if class have value .
you have to know that
getElementsByClassName()
returns an array so you have to access first element (if there is any). Then try accessing value property through this javascript code which is detecting the value based on the length of the value .

```
  var id = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
  if (id.length > 0) {
  var x = id[0].value;
  alert(id[0].value);
  }
```

Then the part where you gonna change the background of the detected class .
You can make if conditions as

```
   if x = x {
   document.getElementsByClassName('classname').style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
```